# failure : retrofit.RetrofitError: 307 Temporary Redirect?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am using the library `com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0`, in order to send data to my server from my android Application.

In fact,when I want to send a request to the server, I found this error:

```
failure : retrofit.RetrofitError: 307 Temporary Redirect
```

I try many idea but the same problem persist.

Please Expert help me to resolve this issue.

Regards

Comment: Post the code for retrofit api creation. Just for the information why don't you use latest version of retrofit with okhttp which has more support for redirect?

Comment: @lotfi can I see your reftrofitClient setup method, also the common service.

Comment: If you must use Retrofit 1.9, see my answer. Otherwise it seems to be the easier way to go with 2.0+ which handles the redirect on 307 automatically as i see.

Answer (score 6):

Edit: if you must not use Retrofit 1.9, switching to a newer version (ie 2.0+) should handle the solution covered below automatically.

---

Looks like your HTTP client (on Android side) should handle this redirection by reading the `Location` value in the response header you are receiving when this happens, which supposed to contain a target redirection URL you ought to hit from the client again.

See their comment [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2131#issuecomment-166493791).

> So for now you need to implement this at the application level (which
>   is hard with Retrofit 1, easier with the forthcoming Retrofit 2) or
>   wait until OkHttp 3.1(ish) when we implement the newest spec.

See also what [307](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E307.html) means.

> Fixing 307 errors - general The 307 response from the Web server
>   should always include an alternative URL to which redirection should
>   occur. If it does, a Web browser will immediately retry the
>   alternative URL. So you never actually see a 307 error in a Web
>   browser, unless perhaps you have a corrupt redirection chain e.g. URL
>   A redirects to URL B which in turn redirects back to URL A. If your
>   client is not a Web browser, it should behave in the same way as a Web
>   browser i.e. immediately retry the alternative URL.
>
> If the Web server does not return an alternative URL with the 307
>   response, then either the Web server sofware itself is defective or
>   the Webmaster has not set up the URL redirection correctly.

See javadoc for Retrofit 1.9.0 to grab the Location header value(URL) from response;

http://static.javadoc.io/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/1.9.0/retrofit/client/Response.html#getHeaders--

```
// omitting null check for brevity
for (Header header : response.getHeaders())
{
    if (header.getName().equals("Location")) {
        redirectURL = header.getValue();
    }
}

// do a redirect to redirectURL
```

Answer (score 5):

I got the solution after a lot of efforts. May be this will help you. If you are getting this error **"203 HTTP 307 Temporary Redirect"** then this trick will help you. 
Append **'/'** to your web service at the end and then check this error goes away. I don't know the reason behind this but it works for me.

For me, my old request web service: https://mydomain/rest/Search. 
Using this URL I was getting **"203 HTTP 307 Temporary Redirect"** where I was able to get a response in POSTMAN and web browser.

My new request web service with the trick: https://mydomain/rest/Search/. 
This **'/'** resolve the issue.

Comment: You save my day! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You are Using Old dependency

Change your dependency from
 "com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0"

to

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

also add this dependency to get full log

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'.
```

Add this method in your Retrofit Client Class

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.connectTimeout("Your_Time", TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.readTimeout("Your_Time", TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("BASE URL")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();
```

Below code is to Handle the Http protocol Exception

```
public Response post(String url, String content) throws IOException {
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(PROTOCOL, content);

    Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(body);
    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
    Response response = this.client.newCall(request).execute();

    if(response.code() == 307) {
        String location = response.header("Location");
        return post(location, content);
    }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle all 307 responses, you can create and add an `Interceptor` to do the job; This interceptor simply creates a new request with the new path which is indicated in the response header "location".

```
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
 .addInterceptor {
                    val request = it.request()
                    val response = it.proceed(request)
                    if (response.code() == 307) {
                        val url = HttpUrl.Builder()
                                .scheme(request.url().scheme())
                                .host(request.url().host())
                                .addPathSegment(response.header("location", request.url().url().path)?: "")
                                .build()

                        val newRequest = Request.Builder()
                                .method(request.method(), request.body())
                                .url(url)
                                .headers(request.headers())
                                .build()

                        return@addInterceptor it.proceed(newRequest)
                    }

                    response
                }
  .build()

Retrofit.Builder().client(client).build()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

You can create an extra interceptor to handle 307

```
private static class RedirectInterceptor implements Interceptor {

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    if (response.code() == 307) {
        request = request.newBuilder()
                .url(response.header("Location"))
                .build();
        response = chain.proceed(request);

    }
    return response;
}
```

}

and add the RedirectInterceptor to your okHttpClient(okhttp2 for example)

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new RedirectInterceptor());
okHttpClient.setFollowRedirects(false);
```

## Solution 2

You can create an ApacheClient with LaxRedirectStrategy

```
private ApacheClient createRedirectClient(){

    return new ApacheClient(HttpClients.custom()
      .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build());
}

RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
   .setEndpoint("http://yourendpoint")
   .setClient(createRedirectClient());
   .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
   .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `HttpLoggingInterceptor` and check the logs. Also cross check with [Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) if your server is returning back with proper response or not for provided input along with parameters.

For `HttpLoggingInterceptor`, this is the following way to configure

```
public RestClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("BASEURL")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
        //APIInterface initiation
        service = retrofit.create(APIInterface.class);
    }
```

Below are the dependencies for the same

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
```

Go through this [Sample tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/) of Retrofit, if you are following some other possibilities of initiating the rest client

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and cracked it by adding a few changes. You can use the HTTP client Interceptor and retain the previous records -> Then update the new redirection URL and proceed with the same chain. Now the magic will happen in the same request call. Happing coding!!

```
public static Retrofit getClient(String url) {
    if (retrofit == null) {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        httpClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                RequestBody originalBody = chain.request().body();
                Request originalRequest = chain.request();
                if(response.code() == 307)
                {
                    String location =  response.header("Location");
                    Log.d(WTBConstant.TAG, "newLoc: "+ location);
                    Request.Builder nwRequest = new Request.Builder().url(location).post(originalBody);
                    Request request = nwRequest.build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);

                }
                return response;
            }
        });

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```